# Accessing scope from parent directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives and I wanted it to use it like so:

```
<m-list m-searchable></m-list>
```

So the two directives were `m-list` and `m-searchable`, now I want to access and manipulate the scope of the `m-list` when I attach the `m-searchable` directive.

I have this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('mList', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: function($rootScope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = 'joey';
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: '...'
    };
  });
```

And my m-searchable looks like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('mSearchable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      replace: true,
      controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
        // I want console.log the scope of the directive where I attached the `m-searchable`
      }
    };
  });
```

I want to `console.log` the scope of the directive where I attached the `m-searchable`. How do I access `vm.name`?

Comment: Adding `require: 'mList'` to your `mSearchable` directive definition will give you access to the `mList` controller via the fourth argument of the `link` function. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i think you will encounter $compile error due to both directive try to have their own isolated scope on the same element.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=mList&p1=mSearchable&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cm-list%20m-searchable%3D%22%22%3E

Updated : better approach as suggested at http://juristr.com/blog/2015/01/learning-ng-directives-access-scope-controller/

is to pass the object between controller & directive

```
<m-list m-searchable name="name"></m-list>

app.directive('mList', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: { name: "="},
  controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
    var vm = this ; 
    vm.name = 'joey';

  },
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  bindToController: true
};
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OKVicRzjuH6L0xedF2qB?p=preview

Comment: I think you're right about the multiple isolate scopes. But accessing sibling scopes like that is a bit dodgy.

Comment: is a bit doge? https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/417201275466690560/TzVjIXv2.jpeg
LOL

Comment: Updated to use better approach on passing object between controller & directives.